# PDF of webpage generated from javascript is not same as the webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, jspdf, html2pdf

I am converting my webpage to PDF with the help of [html2pdf](https://github.com/eKoopmans/html2pdf).The  code which converts webpage to html is as below

```
 $("#btnpdf").click(function() {
        var element = document.getElementById('target');
        html2pdf(element,{
      filename:     'MyPDF.pdf',
      image:        { type: 'jpeg', quality: 1 },

    });
    });
```

The pdf gets generated but the data in it is not properly oriented.The table headers and widgets below it are not exactly in line as seen in webpage.They are somewhat shifted away from there actual position in webpage.

The HTML I am using is as follows

My HTML code

```
<div id="target">
<div class="gridster">
 <table border = "1" class=".table-responsive">
                    <tr>
                        <th colspan="4"  style="background-color:#05345c;">Zone 1</th>
                        <th colspan="4"  style="background-color:#05345c;">Zone  2</th>
                        <th colspan="4"  style="background-color:#05345c;">Zone  3</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="400" align="center" style="background-color:#0085ca">Sub 1</td>
                        <td width="400" align="center" style="background-color:#0085ca">Sub 2</td>
                        <td width="400" align="center" style="background-color:#0085ca">Sub 3</td>
                        <td width="400" align="center" style="background-color:#0085ca">Sub 4</td>
                        <td width="400" align="center" style="background-color:#0085ca">Sub 1</td>
                        <td width="400" align="center" style="background-color:#0085ca">Sub 2</td>
                        <td width="400" align="center" style="background-color:#0085ca">Sub 3</td>
                        <td width="400" align="center" style="background-color:#0085ca">Sub 4</td>
                        <td width="400" align="center" style="background-color:#0085ca">Sub 1</td>
                        <td width="400" align="center" style="background-color:#0085ca">Sub 2</td>
                        <td width="400" align="center" style="background-color:#0085ca">Sub 3</td>
                        <td width="400" align="center" style="background-color:#0085ca">Sub 4</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
    <ul>
    </ul>

</div>
</div>
<div class="controls">
    <button class="js-seralize">Serialize</button>
</div>

<textarea id="log"></textarea>

                <button class="add-button btn btn-success mr-2">Add widget</button>

                <input type="button" class="btn btn-success mr-2" id="btnpdf" value="Download PDF"/>
```

My entire Javascript Code

My JS Code

```
var gridster;


gridster = $(".gridster ul").gridster({
  widget_base_dimensions: [100, 100],
  widget_margins: [5, 5],
    serialize_params: function($w, wgd) {
            return {value:$w.find('textarea').val().trim() , col: wgd.col, row: wgd.row, size_x: wgd.size_x, size_y: wgd.size_y}
        },
  helper: 'clone',
  resize: {
    enabled: true
  }
}).data('gridster');

var json = [{
    "html": "Some big text ", //testing this failed
    "col": 1,
    "row": 1,
    "size_y": 2,
    "size_x": 2
}, {
    "html": "Brand1, Small text", 
    "col": 4,
    "row": 1,
    "size_y": 2,
    "size_x": 2
},

{
    "html": "Very big text",
    "col": 6,
    "row": 1,
    "size_y": 2,
    "size_x": 2
},


{
    "html": "Brand 5",
    "col": 1,
    "row": 3,
    "size_y": 1,
    "size_x": 1
}, {
    "html": "Brand 5",
    "col": 4,
    "row": 3,
    "size_y": 1,
    "size_x": 1
},

{
    "html": "Brand 5",
    "col": 6,
    "row": 3,
    "size_y": 1,
    "size_x": 1
}

];

for(var index=0;index<json.length;index++) {
    gridster.add_widget('<li class="new" ><button class="delete-widget-button" style="float: right;">-</button><textarea class="textareaclass">' +json[index].html+ '</textarea></li>',json[index].size_x,json[index].size_y,json[index].col,json[index].row);
}


    $('.js-seralize').on('click', function() {
        var s = gridster.serialize();
        $('.gridster ul li').each((idx, el) => { // grab the grid elements
            s[idx].html = $('textarea', el).html(); // add the html key/values
        });
        $('#log').val(JSON.stringify(s));
});

$(document).on("click", ".delete-widget-button", function() {
        var gridster = $(".gridster ul").gridster().data('gridster');
        gridster.remove_widget($(this).parent());
    });

     $(document).on( "click", ".add-button", function() {
        var gridster = $(".gridster ul").gridster().data('gridster');      
        //gridster.add_widget('<li><button class="delete-widget-button">-</button></li>', 1, 1);

        // get selected color value
        var color = $("#widget-color").val();

        // build the widget, including a class for the selected color value
        var $widget = $('<li>', {
          'style': 'background-color:' + color
        })
        .append($('<button>', {
          'class': 'delete-widget-button',
          'text':'-'
        }))
        .append($('<textarea>',{
        'class' : 'textareaclass'
        }));

        // add widget to the grid
        gridster.add_widget($widget, 1, 1);


    });

   $("#btnpdf").click(function() {
    var element = document.getElementById('target');
    html2pdf(element,{
  filename:     'MyPDF.pdf',
  image:        { type: 'jpeg', quality: 1 },

});
});
```

[Fiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/x4rakv9z/7/)
The pdf downloaded from Fiddle has the widgets that are not in sync with Sub1, Sub2 etc.Not like the actual webpage shows